# Cassandra 2.0 eating disk space

Tags: cassandra

I am using cassandra in my app and it started eating up disk space much faster than I expected and much faster than defined in manual. Consider this most simple example:

```
CREATE TABLE sizer (
    id ascii,
    time timestamp,
    value float,
    PRIMARY KEY (id,time)
  ) WITH compression={'sstable_compression': ''}"
```

I am turning off compression on purpose to see how many bytes will each record take.

Then I insert few values, I run `nodetool flush` and then I check the size of data file on disk to see how much space did it take.

Results show huge waste of space. Each record take 67 bytes, I am not sure how that is possible.

My id is 13 bytes long at it is saved only once in data file, since it is always the same for testing purposes.

According to: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/webhelp/index.html#cassandra/architecture/architecturePlanningUserData_t.html

Size should be:

- timestamp should be 8 bytes
- value as column name takes 6 bytes
- column value float takes 4 bytes
- column overhead 15 bytes
- TOTAL: 33 bytes

For testing sake, my id is always same, so I have actually only 1 row if I understood correctly.

So, my questions is how do I end up on using 67 bytes instead of 33.

Datafile size is correct, I tried inserting 100, 1000 and 10000 records. Size is always 67 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 overheads discussed in the file.  One is the column overhead, which you have accommodated for.  The second is the row overhead.  And also if you have replication_factor greater than 1 there's an over head for that as well.

Comment: My replication factor is one, I have only 1 row since my id is always same. So I if I insert 1000 values and I have only one row, overall row overhead size is not significant.

Comment: Plus, row overhead is 18 bytes, so even if we add it to the sum, we are still 16 bytes short.